# Is Count() not supported with EF Core and GroupBy()/GroupJoin()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I have a number of Api endpoints that implement filtering and paging via odata or scim.  We currently use EF6 to get the IQueryable by calling a method to project the ModelType to the ResultType.  We then apply the filter to the result type because this is the structure the user sees and can filter on.  Once we have this query we Add Count() to the end of the query to understand what the total count of records available is.  We then Add Skip() and Take() to the initial query without Count() in order to handle paging, wrap the list up in a result that specifies the total count, current count, and the list itself, and return it to the client.  This is a standard flow for odata or scim endpoints. This works great in EF6 but not EF Core in a certain circumstance.  Specifically, if the object we are returning to the client has a collection.  The two queries below illustrate the problem.  You don't really need to understand the database structure or the code. This seems to fail for any query where there's a collection on the base object being returned.  However, this specific example uses a bog standard ASP.Net Identity database where Users is aspnetusers and UserLogins is aspnetuserlogins.  They can be run in LinqPad.

**This works:**

```
Users
.Select(u => new { Id = u.Id, UserName = u.UserName, IsEmailConfirmed = u.EmailConfirmed, LockoutEnd = u.LockoutEnd })
.GroupJoin(UserLogins.Select(x => new { x.UserId, x.LoginProvider }), u => u.Id, ul => ul.UserId, (u, uls) => new { u.Id, u.UserName, u.IsEmailConfirmed, u.LockoutEnd, LoginProviders = uls })
.SelectMany(x => x.LoginProviders.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, l) => new { x.Id, x.UserName, x.IsEmailConfirmed, x.LockoutEnd, LoginProvider = l.LoginProvider })
.GroupBy(x => new {x.Id, x.UserName, x.IsEmailConfirmed, x.LockoutEnd}, x => x.LoginProvider)
.Select(g => new {g.Key.Id, g.Key.UserName, g.Key.IsEmailConfirmed, g.Key.LockoutEnd, LoginProviders = g.Select(x => x)})
.ToList();
```

**This does NOT work:**

```
Users
.Select(u => new { Id = u.Id, UserName = u.UserName, IsEmailConfirmed = u.EmailConfirmed, LockoutEnd = u.LockoutEnd })
.GroupJoin(UserLogins.Select(x => new { x.UserId, x.LoginProvider }), u => u.Id, ul => ul.UserId, (u, uls) => new { u.Id, u.UserName, u.IsEmailConfirmed, u.LockoutEnd, LoginProviders = uls })
.SelectMany(x => x.LoginProviders.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, l) => new { x.Id, x.UserName, x.IsEmailConfirmed, x.LockoutEnd, LoginProvider = l.LoginProvider })
.GroupBy(x => new {x.Id, x.UserName, x.IsEmailConfirmed, x.LockoutEnd}, x => x.LoginProvider)
.Select(g => new {g.Key.Id, g.Key.UserName, g.Key.IsEmailConfirmed, g.Key.LockoutEnd, LoginProviders = g.Select(x => x)})
.Count();
```

The only difference between these two examples is the addition of Count() to the end.  This works fine in EF6 but not EF Core 6 or 7.  We are using Postgresql implementations of EF, so maybe it's a problem with that flavor?  The exception we get is below.

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
   at System.Nullable`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.ClientProjectionRemappingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.ClientProjectionRemappingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.ApplyProjection(Expression shaperExpression, ResultCardinality resultCardinality, QuerySplittingBehavior querySplittingBehavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SelectExpressionProjectionApplyingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryTranslationPostprocessor.Process(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at UserQuery.Main() in C:\Users\brian.adams\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad7\_yrgghvyx\mhemrm\LINQPadQuery:line 5
```

Comment: Ultimately the issue is that this query has never been translatable to pure SQL, and EF6 handles this differently to how EF Core does.

Comment: Prepare bug ticket for EF Core GitHub's repository.  Just changing query to Count should work automatically.

Comment: It's work with with the SQL Server and Sqlite providers. Maybe a bug in the Postgresql provider.

Comment: I also tested with the Postgresql provider, it's work. Can you add a minimal reproductive example?